# Show/Hide google maps api does not work fine

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click on this button, I want the value to change. When I do it, at first it changes the text on button, but the map does not appear. after that, I repeat the process and the code works fine.

```js
function change() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
  if (elem.value == "Show") elem.value = "Hide";
  else elem.value = "Show";
}



function displayMap() {
  if (document.getElementById('map').style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById('map').style.display = "block";
    initialize();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('map').style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```css
#map {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input onclick='change(), displayMap()' type='button' value='Show' id='myButton1'></input>
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:300px;">map</div>
```

Comment: Try initialize then display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assign  `document.getElementById('map').style.display = "none";` globally

Please try this below code

```js
    document.getElementById('map').style.display = "none";// this line is the solution 
    function change() {
      var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
      if (elem.value == "Show") elem.value = "Hide";
      else elem.value = "Show";           
    }
    function displayMap() {
      if (document.getElementById('map').style.display === "none")       {
        document.getElementById('map').style.display = "block";
       } else {
        document.getElementById('map').style.display = "none";
       }
    }
```

```css
 #map {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
 <input onclick='change(), displayMap()' type='button' value='Show' id='myButton1'></input>
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:300px;">map</div>
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to call your `initialize()` function  which is removed from my snippet

Answer (score 0):

`HTMLElement.style` returns the inline style (what is listed in the `style` attribute).

You could use `Window.getComputedStyle()` like this:

```js
var map = document.getElementById('map'),
  btn = document.getElementById("myButton1");

function change() {
  if (btn.value == "Show") btn.value = "Hide";
  else btn.value = "Show";
}

function displayMap() {

  var style = window.getComputedStyle(map);

  if (style.display == "none") {

    map.style.display = "block";

    initialize();

  } else {

    map.style.display = "none";
    
    console.log('hiding');

  }

}


// Placeholder
function initialize() {
  console.log('showing map');
}
```

```css
#map {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background:#333;
}
```

```html
<input onclick='change(), displayMap()' type='button' value='Show' id='myButton1' />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Above method is fine, but I would a more consistent method such as a CSS class, and I would initialize the map in the first place because the way you implemented exhausts the `initialize()`