# why i can't console.log the opacity of the div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can console.log(2), but it didn't work when I want to show the opacity of the 'div'?

```js
let obj = document.getElementById('fade-obj');
let btn = document.getElementById('fade-btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(obj.style.opacity);
    console.log(2);
})
```

```html
<div id="fade-obj" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:#000"></div>
<button id="fade-btn">click</button>
```

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645188/why-element-style-always-return-empty-while-providing-styles-in-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `opacity` to see it

```js
let obj = document.getElementById('fade-obj');
let btn = document.getElementById('fade-btn');
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
       console.log(obj.style.opacity);
});
```

```css
#fade-obj{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div id="fade-obj" style="opacity:1"></div>
<button id="fade-btn">click</button>
```

Or use `window.getComputedStyle(obj).getPropertyValue('opacity')`

```js
let obj = document.getElementById('fade-obj');
let btn = document.getElementById('fade-btn');
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
       console.log(window.getComputedStyle(obj).getPropertyValue('opacity'));
});
```

```css
#fade-obj{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div id="fade-obj"></div>
<button id="fade-btn">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
console.log( window.getComputedStyle(obj).getPropertyValue('opacity');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some default opacity value in order to check value . say `opacity:2`

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('fade-obj').style.opacity);
```

```html
<div id="fade-obj" style="width:30px;height:30px;background:#000;opacity:2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you don't set the opacity, the browser sets it for you. So the opacity is not from the CSS itself. Rather it is computed. Get value using:

```
let obj = document.getElementById('fade-obj');
window.getComputedStyle(obj).getPropertyValue('opacity');
```