# Modal not closing when I click X or outside

Tags: javascript, html, css

The modals I have set up for my website open but do not close when I click the X button or outside.

When I run my code in a browser I can click the button and it works. But then it will not close. I am not sure what the error is or why this does not work.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("WhiteSedan1")
var btn1 = document.getElementById("BtnWhiteSedan")
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn1.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 50x;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="BtnWhiteSedan">White Sedan</a>
</div>

<div id="WhiteSedan1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p class="text-center">
      Model: Toyota<br> Mileage: 28,000 km <br> Transmission: Auto<br> Cost: $10,000
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

My goal is when I click the X or outside the modal, the modal closes.

Comment: The `×` button is working fine. `padding-top: 50x;` is a typo. Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `onclick`.

Comment: The 'x' button is functional and also because of your CSS, you can only click on the background of the modal. check this repl out for clarification https://repl.it/join/rtrznwll-programmemitch

Comment: Related: [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028037/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed some problems:

- height of the modal, taking the 100% of the space so influencing the click
- put a listener on the document, which will trigger the modal if the status is `block` or if it's the button.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("WhiteSedan1")
var btn1 = document.getElementById("BtnWhiteSedan")
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if(btn1.contains(event.target)){
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }else{
    if (!modal.contains(event.target) && modal.style.display === "block" ||  span.contains(event.target)) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 50x;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1px;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="BtnWhiteSedan">White Sedan</a>
</div>

<div id="WhiteSedan1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p class="text-center">
      Model: Toyota<br> Mileage: 28,000 km <br> Transmission: Auto<br> Cost: $10,000
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Now it's closing when clicking inside the modal too

Comment: here you are! Try to be nice, we're trying to help each other ;)

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest combining all opening / closing modal event listeners into one, otherwise multiple event listeners run consecutively, but you only want *one* action to happen.

One way of achieving this behavior is to check for `event.target`: if the `BtnWhiteSedan` element is clicked, open the modal; otherwise, if neither the modal nor anything *inside* the modal is clicked, with the exception of the `×` button, close the modal. See [`Node.prototype.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains).

Since `event` is only used for `event.target`, use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the `target` property directly.

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("WhiteSedan1"),
  openButton = document.getElementById("BtnWhiteSedan"),
  [
    closeButton
  ] = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
  if (target === openButton) {
    modal.hidden = false;
  }
  else if(target !== modal && !modal.contains(target) || target === closeButton){
    modal.hidden = true;
  }
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover, .close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc">
  <a id="BtnWhiteSedan" class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">White Sedan</a>
</div>
<div id="WhiteSedan1" class="modal" hidden>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p class="text-center">Model: Toyota<br> Mileage: 28,000 km<br>Transmission: Auto<br> Cost: $10,000</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It’s [not always robust to check for CSS properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55071684/4642212). Use the [`hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) instead, or use a class name and `modal.classList.has("hidden")`, `modal.classList.add("hidden")`, `modal.classList.remove("hidden")`, with `.hidden { display: none; }` in your CSS. See [`Element.prototpye.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). If you do use the `hidden` attribute, remove the CSS default, and simply add a `hidden` attribute to your modal as I’ve done in the code above.

I’ve also replaced [`var` by `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21237105/4642212), [`onclick` by `addEventListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6348494/4642212), and [abstract equality by strict equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/4642212). I’ve also used more semantic variable names (e.g. `closeButton` rather than `span`).

There was also a typo in your CSS: `padding-top: 50x;` instead of `padding-top: 50px;`.