# How do I get the top style value with javascript?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    
    
<style>
    #playerOne{position:absolute;top:500px;left: 500px;border:3px solid green; height: 500px;width:500px; background-color:black}   
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
    <div id="playerOne"></div>
    
    </div>  
<script>
var playerOneDiv = document.querySelector("#playerOne");    
    
console.log(playerOneDiv.style.top);

    
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting anything in my console when I try it like this

I am trying to mimic w3schools example but am having no luck with it, thank you.

http://w3schools-fa.ir/jsref/prop_style_top.html

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+style+property+is+blank+if+set+in+css) of [Why element.style always return empty in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50645188/4642212).

Comment: yep kinda it does thanks, Is there a way to accomplish finding the value of the top or left value? As that is how my question was worded

Comment: Yes, of course. The accepted answer mentions [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) which gets _any and all_ CSS values.

Comment: Of if you don't every style related, and just the 'top', you can use `.getClientBoundingRect().top`

Comment: I want a value not read only, is getclientboundingrect going to give me read only? @RandyCasburn

Comment: Answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect#notes

Answer (score 0):

the issue is window imposing style from style sheet after display rendered. If you grab the window property you would be able to get imposed style properties. Please try by updating your script using following code:

```
<script>
    var playerOneDiv = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#playerOne")).top;
    console.log(playerOneDiv);
</script>
```

I hope this will help you. Thank you.