# I want to cycle through plain text underline and line-through by clicking on a span

Tags: javascript, dom, click

As said above, I want to have JS cycle through textDecoration as I click on a span. I found a fragment of this in another answer that I cannot find anymore and (tried to) modify it.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
            <span>A</span> <span>B</span> <span>C</span> <span>D</span> 
        </div>
```

JS

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
if (container.addEventListener) {
    container.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
}
else if (container.attachEvent) {
    container.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
        return clickHandler.call(container, e || window.event);
    });
}

function clickHandler(event) {
    var span = event.target;
    if (span.style.textDecoration == 'none') {
        span.style.textDecoration = 'underline'
    }
    else if (span.style.textDecoration == 'underline') {
        span.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
    }
    else if (span.style.textDecoration == 'line-through') {
        span.style.textDecoration = 'none'
    }
}
```

I think the issue is with using span as the object, but I am not sure how to do it more correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because of this:

> Element.style returns the inline style used in HTML document and since the style is not set directly in HTML you will get an empty value

So, I have set it to none in the starting. Then it will work.
[Check out this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645188/why-element-style-always-return-empty-in-js) to see why

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span')
for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
   spans[i].style.textDecoration = "none" // setting default
}

container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    clickHandler(e)
});

function clickHandler(event) {
    var span = event.target;
    if (span.style.textDecoration == 'none') {
        span.style.textDecoration = 'underline'
    }
    else if (span.style.textDecoration == 'underline') {
        span.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
    }
    else if (span.style.textDecoration == 'line-through') {
        span.style.textDecoration = 'none'
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
      <span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span><span>D</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
span.style.textDecoration == ''
```

instead of

```
span.style.textDecoration == 'none'
```

Also assigning:

```
span.style.textDecoration = ''
```

instead of

```
span.style.textDecoration = 'none'
```